# MAVEN JMETER : not able to generate dashboard result

Tags: jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am trying to create mvn based meter project based on keyword driven frame, on execution, it work fine, but report is basic, I need a report which has more information like latency, throughput, etc, I tried a lot but no success.

I tried ant plugin but it given me error :

```
Executing tasks
     [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jorphan/util/JMeterException
     [java]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
     [java]     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
     [java]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
     [java]     at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:251)
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
     [java]     ... 5 more
     [java] JMeter home directory was detected as: /Users/admin/Desktop/demo/target/jmeter
```

Below is my POM File

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>jmeter-maven</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>jmeter-maven</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
                            <xms>1024</xms>
                            <xmx>1024</xmx>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-Xprof</argument>
                                <argument>-Xfuture</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
                        <propertiesUser>
                            <users>${users}</users>
                            <rampUp>${rampUp}
                            </rampUp>
                            <loop>${loopcount}</loop>
                            <url>${url}</url>
                            <suite>${suite}</suite>
                    <jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes>
                    <jmeter.save.saveservice.label>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.label>
                    <jmeter.save.saveservice.latency>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.latency>
                    <jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code>
                    <jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message>
                    <jmeter.save.saveservice.successful>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.successful>
                    <jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts>
                    <jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name>
                    <jmeter.save.saveservice.time>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.time>
                        </propertiesUser>
                        <testFilesIncluded>
                            <jMeterTestFile>testplans/jmeter-maven.jmx</jMeterTestFile>
                        </testFilesIncluded>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>pre-site</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <mkdir dir="${basedir}/target/jmeter/results/dashboard" />
                            <copy file="${basedir}/src/test/resources/reportgenerator.properties" 
                                  tofile="${basedir}/target/jmeter/bin/reportgenerator.properties" />
                            <copy todir="${basedir}/target/jmeter/bin/report-template">
                                <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/test/resources/report-template" />
                            </copy>
                            <java jar="${basedir}/target/jmeter/bin/ApacheJMeter.jar" fork="true">
                                <arg value="-g" />
                                <arg value="${basedir}/target/jmeter/results/*.jtl" />
                                <arg value="-o" />
                                <arg value="${basedir}/target/jmeter/results/dashboard/" />
                            </java>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lazerycode.jmeter/jmeter-maven-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am following below github link to [github](https://github.com/aishwaryD/jmeter-keyword-driven-framework)

Need an help for same , I tried all but not able to fixed this.

Answer (score 2):

Please "don't follow below links to github" without understanding what they are doing, you're trying to use [JMeter Maven Plugin 1.4.1](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/releases/tag/jmeter-maven-plugin-1.4.1) which is designed for working with [JMeter 2.6](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-26-new-gui/) which was good in year 2012 but it doesn't have any [HTML Reporting Dashboard capabilities](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html).

The current version of JMeter Maven Plugin is [3.0.0](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/releases/tag/3.0.0) and you should be following official documentation and according to it [generating HTML dashboard](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Generating-Reports) is as simple as:

```
<generateReports>true</generateReports>
```

Full *pom.xml* just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <users>1</users>
        <rampup>1</rampup>
        <loopcount>1</loopcount>
        <suite>foo</suite>
        <url>http://example.com</url>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Generate JMeter configuration -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>configuration</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>configure</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>results</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <generateReports>true</generateReports>
                    <testFilesIncluded>
                        <jmeterTestFile>test1.jmx</jmeterTestFile>
                        <jmeterTestFile>test2.jmx</jmeterTestFile>
                    </testFilesIncluded>
                    <propertiesUser>
                        <users>${users}</users>
                        <rampUp>${rampup}</rampUp>
                        <loop>${loopcount}</loop>
                        <url>${url}</url>
                        <suite>${suite}</suite>
                    </propertiesUser>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Hi Dimitri, Thanks this works for me.  When I want to add drivers(jar and dll  files) for MariaDB, and MS SQL database where do I have to add these drivers when I use this Jmeter Maven plugin ? Maybe as Maven dependencys ? And my custom Java Request samplers ?  You have any idea ?

Comment: https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-Excluding-libraries-to-from-the-classpath